# How do i change the language of the browser(Chrome) using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently working on a code which must scrape Instagram videos and download them, the problem is that when trying to use it on another computer which has another default language, the code does not work due to this.

So what I want to do is to be able to change the language of the search engine

Previously I tried is

```
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.37""')
options.add_argument("--lang= es")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,options=options)
```

also try this

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

but both codes did not change the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its with the space in `--lang= es`. I tried to change language in my browser.

With below lines it did change the language to `hindi`.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang=hi")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path",options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

But with space in `lang= hi`, it dint work.